# Google Safebrowsing search returns threat but API does not

Tags: safe-browsing

When I try to search computerquestions.on.nimp.org, Google Safe browsing UI returns that the link is harmful: 
[Google Safe browsing UI Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eASdz.png)

But when I try to use the "https://safebrowsing.googleapis.com/v4/threatMatches:find" to search for computerquestions.on.nimp.org, it returns an empty object. 
How can I get the same result?

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this? I am encountering the same issue.

Comment: no. unless you use the transparency report api, the result will be the same. but I can't find the documentation on how to interpret the response of transparency report api